# Shiny initial textAreaInput value and reactive after each button press

Tags: r, shiny

### Description

I have a `textAreaInput` box that I want to start with a default value.  The user can click 2 `actionButtons` (<kbd>Submit</kbd> & <kbd>Random Comment</kbd>).  <kbd>Submit</kbd> updates the comment from the `textAreaInput` for further processing (plot, etc.) while <kbd>Random Comment</kbd> sends a new random value to `textAreaInput` (the user may type in the `textAreaInput` box as well).  I almost have it but can't get the app to update `textAreaInput`'s `value` until the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button is pressed.

### Question

I want it to be updated when <kbd>Random Comment</kbd> is pressed but still allow the user to erase the text box and type their own text.  How can I make the app do this?

[image]

### MWE

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(stringi)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      column(2,
        uiOutput("randcomment"),
        br(),
        div(
            actionButton("randtext", "Random Comment", icon = icon("quote-right")),
            div(actionButton("submit", "Submit", icon = icon("refresh")), style="float:right")
        )

      ),
      column(4, div(verbatimTextOutput("commenttext"), style = 'margin-top: 2cm;'))
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {

        output$randcomment <- renderUI({
            commentUi()
        })

        comment_value <- reactiveValues(default = 0)

        observeEvent(input$submit,{
            comment_value$default <- input$randtext
        })

        renderText(input$randtext)

        commentUi <- reactive({

            if (comment_value$default == 0) {
                com <- stri_rand_lipsum(1)
            } else {
                com <- stri_rand_lipsum(1)
            }

            textAreaInput("comment", label = h3("Enter Course Comment"), 
                value = com, height = '300px', width = '300px')
        })

        output$commenttext <- renderText({ input$comment })


    }
  )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd approach this a little bit differently.  I would use `reactiveValues` to populate both of the fields, and then use two `observeEvents` to control the contents of the `reactiveValues`.

I don't think you need a `reactive` at all in this situation.  `reactive` is good when you want immediate processing.  If you want to maintain control over when the value is processed, use `reactiveValues`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(stringi)

shinyApp( 
  ui = fluidPage(
    column(2,
           uiOutput("randcomment"),
           br(),
           div(
             actionButton("randtext", "Random Comment", icon = icon("quote-right")),
             div(actionButton("submit", "Submit", icon = icon("refresh")), style="float:right")
           )

    ),
    column(4, div(verbatimTextOutput("commenttext"), style = 'margin-top: 2cm;'))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    # Reactive lists -------------------------------------------------------
    # setting the initial value of each to the same value.
    initial_string <- stri_rand_lipsum(1)
    comment_value <- reactiveValues(comment = initial_string,
                                    submit = initial_string)

    # Event observers ----------------------------------------------------
    observeEvent(input$randtext,
      {
        comment_value$comment <- stri_rand_lipsum(1)
      }
    )

    # This prevents the comment_value$submit from changing until the 
    # Submit button is clicked. It changes to the value of the input
    # box, which is updated to a random value when the Random Comment
    # button is clicked.
    observeEvent(input$submit,
      {
        comment_value$submit <- input$comment
      }
    )

    # Output Components -------------------------------------------------
    # Generate the textAreaInput
    output$randcomment <- renderUI({
      textAreaInput("comment", 
                    label = h3("Enter Course Comment"), 
                    value = comment_value$comment, 
                    height = '300px', 
                    width = '300px')
    })

    # Generate the submitted text display
    output$commenttext <- 
      renderText({ 
        comment_value$submit 
      })
  }
)
```

#### Some comments on your code

I struggled a little with determining what your code was doing. Part of the reason was that your server function was organized a bit chaotically.  Your components are

- output
- reactive list
- observer
- output (but not assigned to a slot...superfluous)
- reactive object
- output

I'd recommend grouping your reactives together, your observers together, and your outputs together.  If you have truly separate systems, you can break the systems into different sections of code, but have them follow a similar pattern (I would claim that these two boxes are part of the same system)

Your `commentUi` reactive has a strange `if-else` construction. It always sets `com` to a random string. What's more, the `if-else` construction isn't really necessary because no where in your code do you ever update `comment_value$default`--it is always 0.  It looks like you may have been trying to base this off of an action button at some point, and then concluded (rightly) that that wasn't a great option.

Also, I would advise against building UI components in your reactive objects.  You'll find your reactives are much more flexible and useful if they return values and then build any UI components within the `render` family of functions.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I have received.  Thanks for the time to write it.  The constructive feedback is really helpful.  Thanks for taking the time to post.

Comment: I'm glad you took it constructively.  I almost didn't include the criticisms after looking at your reputation.